# How to set a default value in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I have the following select field:

```html
{%verbatim%}
<select class="form-control" ng-model="l.s_value" ng-change="getval(k)" ng-options="s.rank as (s.rank +s.generic_value) for s in list">
  {%endverbatim%}
</select>
```

My list is full of values and there is no default to set if the user dont want to set any values. Is there any way to put default value in ng-options? I not interested to use `ng-repeat`, if `ng-repeat` we can actually put one option as "selected string". And my other doubt is how to append any string in between the `s.rank +s.generic_value` like `s.rank + - + s.generic_value` Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notreally Marcel, didnt worked as expected